# Serving Java web application with Windows Server

Tags: windows, java, windows-server-2008

I have a dream to build a home server where I deploy my own java web applications for LAN access only. I have got also a Windows Server machine for running them. I am little bit outdated about all server related things, so I want to know is there any possible advantage of that server ability of my platform?

Have I understood right, that Java web applications are run only at Java specific servers and there is no use of the Windows Server program in this case, meaning that I have to build a Java server inside the other server to run any Java program?

Comment: I clarified the question. I am asking about Java web applications, so I want to have my own site inside my home network and that site is running with Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked aroung StackExchange and found a [StackOverFlow question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050385/deploy-a-java-web-application-on-windows-server-2003) that makes it clear, that you need an Java Application Server to run Java applications even if you were already having a Windows server as your machine.

I thought first that any server will do, but this Q&A pair says I need still that server inside server before Java Web Application can be served. Mainly I suppose the interpreting of Java language at run time needs that Java specific server.

Comment: You can use [jFastCGI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jfastcgi/) to have IIS communicate with the servlet through FastCGI. Or you can use [just plain Java and FastCGI (no servlets)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15033764/309483).

Answer (score 5):

To run Java programs on your Windows-2008 server you only need to install on it the Java Runtime Environment (JRE) which you can download from Oracle's Java website.

To run a Java web application you need to first install the corresponding [web application framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks#Java)

Comment: What about Java Web Applications? That's actually what I meant with Java Applications. Sorry my unclear question..

Comment: @mico, you need to select and install one of the many "web application frameworks". Which one depends on what you want to do. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks#Java